# pandas loc code to replace column contents no longer working following software update, key error but key is there

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror, pandas-loc

I have some code which looks for the full name of a browser in a column and where found overwrites with a short name. this is to allow simplified filtering without version numbers in visualisations.

This code has worked fine for most of 2020. I get a new work laptop, reinstalled and updated anaconda and now it is giving a KeyError.

The code:

```
#clean up browser column data to remove version numbers
#for column 'Browser' in dataframe if object (string) contains Ch   Chrome else Sa  Safari else Ed  Edge else MS    MSIE else Fi    Firefox else Mo Mozilla else    Other 

def browser_clean(webchat):

    webchat.loc[webchat['Browser'].str[:2] == 'Ch', 'Browser'] = 'Chrome'
    webchat.loc[webchat['Browser'].str[:2] == 'Sa', 'Browser'] = 'Safari'
    webchat.loc[webchat['Browser'].str[:2] == 'Ed', 'Browser'] = 'Edge'
    webchat.loc[webchat['Browser'].str[:2] == 'MS', 'Browser'] = 'MSIE'
    webchat.loc[webchat['Browser'].str[:2] == 'Fi', 'Browser'] = 'Firefox'
    webchat.loc[webchat['Browser'].str[:2] == 'Mo', 'Browser'] = 'Mozilla'

    return webchat
```

I've checked the key is there using:

```
print (webchat['Browser'])
```

with the output:

```
0               Safari 13.1.1
1         Chrome 85.0.4183.83
2        Chrome 84.0.4147.136
3        Chrome 79.0.3945.136
4         Chrome 85.0.4183.81
                 ...         
17813     Chrome 85.0.4183.81
17814           Safari 13.1.2
17815     Chrome 85.0.4183.83
17816    Chrome 75.0.3770.143
17817           Safari 13.1.2
Name: Browser, Length: 17818, dtype: object
```

so it looks to me like the key is there?

The error message I see when I now run the code is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-bcf8735bc33d> in <module>()
      5 webchat_drop_uw = drop_unwanted(webchat_dropped)
      6 webchat_new_cols = month_year(webchat_drop_uw)
----> 7 webchat_cleaned = browser_clean(webchat_new_cols)
      8 webchat_newOScol = short_OS(webchat_cleaned)
      9 webchat_final = strip_data(webchat_newOScol)

<ipython-input-8-b9c27fc07f46> in browser_clean(webchat)
      4 def browser_clean(webchat):
      5 
----> 6     webchat.loc[webchat['Browser'].str[:2] == 'Ch', 'Browser'] = 'Chrome'
      7     webchat.loc[webchat['Browser'].str[:2] == 'Sa', 'Browser'] = 'Safari'
      8     webchat.loc[webchat['Browser'].str[:2] == 'Ed', 'Browser'] = 'Edge'

C:\Users\8485823\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    880 
    881         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 882             return self._get_value(key)
    883 
    884         if is_hashable(key):

C:\Users\8485823\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
    988 
    989         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
--> 990         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    991         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
    992 

C:\Users\8485823\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    356                 except ValueError as err:
    357                     raise KeyError(key) from err
--> 358             raise KeyError(key)
    359         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    360 

KeyError: 'Browser'
```

***updated***
key error coming in from column being dropped by this prior function, which it didn't used to do:

```
# remove unwanted columns (contain data)
def drop_unwanted(webchat):
        
    webchat.drop(
        labels = ["Visitor Name", 
                "MCS", 
                "Agent Name", 
                "Agent Login Name", 
                "Agent Full Name",
                "Agent Group", 
                "Chat Start Reason", 
                "Interactive", 
                "Engagement ID", 
                "Goal", 
                "Campaign", 
                "Target Audience", 
                "Country", 
                "State", 
                "City", 
                "Organization", 
                "IP Address", 
                "Personal Info Exists", 
                "Customer Info Exists", 
                "Marketing Source Exists", 
                "Lead Exists", 
                "Visitor Error Exists", 
                "Service Activity Exists", 
                "Viewed Product Exists", 
                "Transaction Exists", 
                "Cart Update Exists", 
                "Pre-Chat Survey Exists", 
                "Search Content Exists", 
                "CoBrowse - Num Sessions", 
                "CoBrowse - Num Interactive Sessions", 
                "Alerted MCS", 
                "Chat MCS"
               ],
        axis = 1,
        #index = None,
        errors ='ignore',
        inplace = True,
        )
        
    return webchat
```

Any ideas why it would drop a column that's not listed in my drop list?

Comment: Verify that `webchat_new_cols` has a column `Browser`

Comment: it's not! same key error. it is in the one before webchat_drop_uw. 
now I've a new mystery as to why the code is dropping a column I'm not asking it to drop. I'll update the question

Comment: You need to verify the columns in webchat dataframe before and after the drop_unwanted method call.

Comment: @ScottBoston it's not in the DF after the drop_unwanted method but i don't understand why it's dropping out. updated code in question